# Loop Option Values in the dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to loop the value options displayed in the dropdown menu in an HTML web page. The option values seems to be in alpha numeric for which i write the code below, it is reading all the values within correctly, but i am not able to loop it continuously. Its showing the error stating "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'"

Condition 1: If option value is 0 the driver should close
Condition 2: If not it should read the next option value and work accordingly.

Any Guide through this will be appreciated.

select_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "<ID_Name>")
options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
for element in options:
i = element.get_attribute("value")
print(i)
if i == 0:
driver.close()
continue
else:
select_box.select_by_value(str(i))

Comment: Is select_box a webelement using the Select tag.

Comment: no its a variable defined

Comment: Could you provide the HTML of `select_box` and/or your full python code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sure just a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.select_by_value()` cannot be used on webelements directly, you have first to import the following library

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

and then do one of the following

```
Select(select_box).select_by_index(...)
Select(select_box).select_by_value(...)
Select(select_box).select_by_visible_text(...)
```

Comment: its already imported

Comment: @SatyamJhawar but you are using `select_box.select_by_value(str(i))` instead of `Select(select_box).select_by_value(str(i))`